# How to verify Firebase ID token on App Engine in Go

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, go, firebase-authentication

The Firebase documentation, [Verify ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), explains how to [Verify ID tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk).

But first the [Firebase Admin SDK must be setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/). After installing the Go Admin SDK, with `go get firebase.google.com/go` it must be initialized (I *assume* this code is placed in the HTTP server `main` function):

```golang
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}
```

**Question #1:** I have no `context` in my App Engine app because in [Migrating from the App Engine Go SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/go-differences) it states:

> Use [request.Context()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) or your preferred context instead of using
>   [appengine.NewContext](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference#NewContext).

AFACT the [request.Context()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) is available from within an HTTP Handler Function. See the [HandleFunc example](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_HandleFunc) on [golang.org](https://golang.org/). Using the *request* context would require **initializing** the Firebase SDK for every HTTP request!

**Question #2**: How can I get a reference to my Firebase `app` from within an HTTP handler?

```golang
func main() {
    // ------> Initialize the Firebase Go SDK. <------ \\
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
    }

    // My usual boilerplate for App Engine.
    http.HandleFunc("/api/foo", fooHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/api/bar", barHandler)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s", port)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

There are some very useful looking functions in the [firebase/firebase-admin-go](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/snippets/auth.go) repo, but without a `context` (for the HTTP request?) and no way to share `app` with my HTTP handlers, I can't work-out how to use them:

```golang
// ==================================================================
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens
// ==================================================================

func verifyIDToken(ctx context.Context, app *firebase.App, idToken string) *auth.Token {
    // [START verify_id_token_golang]
    client, err := app.Auth(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error getting Auth client: %v\n", err)
    }

    token, err := client.VerifyIDToken(ctx, idToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error verifying ID token: %v\n", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Verified ID token: %v\n", token)
    // [END verify_id_token_golang]

    return token
}
```

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Comment: @karan-singh Unfortunately not. But I also haven't tried beyond posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

As treethought pointed out, context is of little importance for you. You can use `context.Background()`.
The context you are passing to firebase API is not the context you are interested in. That's the context used to goroutines management.
What you need in fact is a context that is provided by the http server you are using. You use that server's context to get the data from the request, parse it,  and pass it as `idToken`.
For example, if you use [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin), this is usually achieved by adding middleware that has a contract:

```
return func(c *gin.Context) {
    ....
    c.Next()
}
```

Inside it you use your firebase app/client to call `verifyIDToken` and then decide if you want to chain the request further to your handlers(`c.Next()`) or abort(`c.Abort()`)

You need to encapsulate the state, in our case firebase client, inside that middleware so you create it as an object/struct with a method that returns a function with the signature specified above.
Here's an [example](https://github.com/lon9/gin-firebase-auth/blob/master/firebase_auth.go).
I didn't need the flexibility provided by a separate `unAuthorized` function, and also I store the token inside the cookie, so in my case it became:

```
package middleware

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go/v4"
    "firebase.google.com/go/v4/auth"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type firebaseAuthMiddleware struct {
    client *auth.Client
}

func CreateFirebaseMiddleware() *firebaseAuthMiddleware {
    app := initFirebaseAppDefault(context.Background())
    authClient := createAuthClient(context.Background(), app)
    return &firebaseAuthMiddleware{
        client: authClient,
    }
}

func (fam *firebaseAuthMiddleware) FirebaseAuthMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if strings.HasSuffix(c.Request.URL.Path, "/query") {
            idTokenCookie, err := c.Request.Cookie("FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN")
            if idTokenCookie == nil || err != nil {
                buildUnauthorizedResponse(c)
                return
            }
            var objmap graphQLMessage
            var bodyBytes []byte
            if c.Request.Body != nil {
                bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
            }

            // Restore the io.ReadCloser to its original state
            c.Request.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
            json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &objmap)
            //stringBody := string(body)
            token, err := fam.client.VerifyIDToken(context.Background(), idTokenCookie.Value)
            if err != nil {
                buildUnauthorizedResponse(c)
                return
            }
            if objmap.Variables["userId"] != token.UID {
                buildUnauthorizedResponse(c)
                return
            }
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}

func buildUnauthorizedResponse(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{
        "status":  http.StatusUnauthorized,
    })
    c.Abort()
}

type graphQLMessage struct {
    Variables map[string]string
    Query string
    OperationName string
}

func initFirebaseAppDefault(ctx context.Context) *firebase.App {
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
    }
    return app
}

func createAuthClient(ctx context.Context, app *firebase.App) *auth.Client {
    client, err := app.Auth(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error getting Auth client: %v\n", err)
    }
    return client
}
```

And then register the middleware in main:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler"
    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/playground"
    mw "github.com/wnd-engineering/storeback/middleware"
    "log"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(mw.CreateFirebaseMiddleware().FirebaseAuthMiddleware())
    r.POST("/query", graphqlHandler())
    r.GET("/", playgroundHandler())
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just create a new context `context.Background()` for example.